# Why do I have to authenticate the user with firebase after he has already signed-in?

Tags: java, firebase, android-studio, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I have implemented google sign-in in my android app with firebase authentication by following the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin). However, I am still trying to understand the code and the logic behind it.
So, after the user has successfully signed-in with his gmail account, the method ***firebaseAuthWithGoogle*** is called with the account information passed as an argument:

```
firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);
```

Here's its definition:

```
private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount acct) {
        // We will put the data coming from the google account in MySQL database
        Log.d(TAG, "firebaseAuthWithGoogle:" + acct.getId());
    AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.getIdToken(), null);
    mFirebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                        Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:success");
                        FirebaseUser user = mFirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

                    } else {
                        // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                        Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential:failure", task.getException());

                    }

                    // ...
                }
            });
}
```

}

I have tried explaining this to myself according to the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin):

After a user successfully signs-in,

```
GoogleSignInAccount account = task.getResult(ApiException.class);
firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account); // Calling firebaseAuthWithGoogle
```

get an ***ID token*** from the ***GoogleSignInAccount object***, 
exchange it for a ***Firebase credential***,

```
AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.getIdToken(), null);
```

and authenticate with Firebase

```
mFirebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
```

using the ***Firebase credential***.

What is not **100% clear** to me is:
1. Why do I have to authenticate with Firebase if the user has already signed-in?
2. What does the role that Firebase authentication plays if the user is already signed-in?
3. What does signing-in with Firebase credential mean if the user is already signed-in?

I know this might sound trivial to some of you, but for me the whole sign-in flow is quite vague, especially with the Firebase authentication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you authenticate using firebase, then you can access the currently logged in user, by doing the following :

```
FirebaseUser user = mFirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
```

By retrieving the `user`, you can also retrieve the `userId` which you can use to connect to the Firebase Database.

You can also check if the user is still logged in when opening the application again:

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
if (user != null) {
    // User is signed in
} else {
    // No user is signed in
}
```

And redirect the user to the page after login

Comment: Thanks. So that's the whole point of using firebase authentication? What is the firebase credential sign-in about? Is it different from the initial sign-in by the user? or it is the initial sign-in. This is what confused more.